# pass a target name to dependency list in makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to write a makefile to build a set of c++ programs in the same directory that have independent source code, but similar compilation rules and shared dependencies (common headers).

```
/path/to/project/
    peformance.h
    vector.h
    pqvm.cpp
    quantum/
        quantum-tbb.h
        quantum-sequential.h
        ...
    tests/
        grainsize.cpp
        kronecker.cpp
        sigma-z.cpp
        ...
        Makefile
```

I want to compile the sources in the `tests` folder, each source to a corresponding executable. Below is the makefile I am trying to use; there seems to be a problem in the line `$(TARGETS): %.o`.

I want to refer to the current target's name (e.g. `grainsize`) and have it depend on its corresponding object file (e.g. `grainsize.o`), neither `%.o` nor `$@.o` seem to work. I could change the line to `$(TARGETS): $(OBJECTS)` but then every target would depend on all the objects, triggering a lot of unnecessary recompilation on each change.

So basically: how do I correctly refer to a target name in its dependency list?
I am aware of this related question: [Passing target name to a dependency in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573869/passing-target-name-to-a-dependency-in-makefile), but I can't see how it would apply to this problem.

```
CXX     = g++
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
DEPS    = ../performance.h $(wildcard ../quantum/*.h) ../vector.h
TARGETS = $(basename $(SOURCES))
OBJECTS = $(addsuffix .o, $(TARGETS))

INCPATH = -I../../local/include
LIBPATH = -L../../local/lib
LIBS    = -lpfm -lpapi -ltbb
OFLAGS  = -Wall -O2
DFLAGS  = -g3
CFLAGS  = -march=native $(OFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $(LIBPATH) -fopenmp

UNAME   = $(shell uname)
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
  LIBS += -lrt
endif

.PHONY: all

all: $(TARGETS)

#for each target: link its object file to the libraries and produce an executable binary
#this does not work as expected
$(TARGETS): %.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $@.o $(LIBS) -o $@

#compile each target to its object file
#this works as expected
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

This is the error message on the command line:

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `%.o', needed by `grainsize'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
$(TARGETS): %.o
    ...
```

is not a pattern rule; there is a `%` in the prerequisite list, but not in the target. So Make interprets the `%` literally, and there's no such file as `%.o`.

Try this:

```
$(TARGETS): % : %.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@
```

This is a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). Also, I've changed `$@.o` (which would work but is a kludge) to `$^` (which means "all of the prerequisites", and is more robust and easier on the eyes).

Comment: +1 Additionally, `$^` will include any other dependencies; this is usually a good thing, but if you don't want that for whatever reason, `$<` gets you the first dependency. (Additional dependencies could be declared outside this pattern rule, so you could say `foo: bar.o` as an additional dependency for `foo`, and still have this pattern rule work for `foo` as well as the other `$(TARGETS)`.)